# Change served SSL certifiate dependent on client IP in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I have two SSL certificates, `foo.crt` and `bar.crt`. Both certificates use the same key, `foo.key`. I want my Nginx to send `foo.crt` as the SSL certificate when the client IP matches `192.168.1.0/24`, and `bar.crt` when it does not.

I've tried using the Geo module and an `if` directive as follows:

```
geo $local {
    default 0;
    192.168.1.0/24 1;
}
...
server {
    ssl_certificate bar.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key foo.key;
    if ($local) {
        ssl_certificate foo.crt;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, Nginx gives me the error `"ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here`.

Is there a way of doing this without an `if` directive?

Comment: Using a [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block, maybe?

Comment: afaik is your SSL one closing bracket too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (not tested):

```
geo $cert {
    default bar.crt;
    192.168.1.0/24 foo.crt;
}
...
server {
    ssl_certificate $cert;
    ssl_certificate_key foo.key;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had to put quotes around `bar.crt` and `foo.crt`, but this worked. i also had to change the permissions on the certificates to allow the Nginx user to read them. thank you!